# Exclude a user from a launchd agent?

Tags: macos, launchd, plist

I have launchd plists at the administrator per-user level, particularly inside:

- `/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons`

I'd like to avoid that some of those services could start only for one user (possibly avoiding to move all the plists to each `~/Library/LaunchAgents`), which is the simplest way?

**Edit:** To restate, if I have an agent in `/Library/LaunchAgent`, is there a way to disable it for a particular user or group of users, without copying the plist into each `~/Library/LaunchAgent`?

Comment: i'm assuming this is Mac OS X we're talking about?

Comment: You'd like to avoid what?

Comment: If I have an agent in /Library/LaunchAgent ... is there a way to disable it for an user or a group of users?

Without copy the plist in each ~/Library/LaunchAgent...

Comment: @compriots: that's much clearer, thanks.  i've added it into the question body.

Comment: Have you tried just adding a check for the username in the scripts? (The quick and dirty method)

Answer (score 0):

That user would have to explicitly unload the system level job to try to put the cart before the horse.

There is no process to delay a system job until a user logs in so you would have to somehow add that into the launchd code as an extension. It is open source, but it seems like a big undertaking and breaks with the flow of the tool.